# Propagating CSS variables in composited elements

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I've got an element (the host) that includes another element (the child).

How can I propagate the value of a CSS variable from the host to the child when the CSS variable is set on the host?

### Example:

```
<!-- Host Element, includes <child-element> -->

<dom-module id="host-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      child-element {
        --button-color: var(--menu-button-color);
      }
    </style>

    <child-element><child-element>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<!-- Child Element, is declared within <host-element> -->

<dom-module id="child-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      button {
        color: var(--button-color);
      }
    </style>

    <button> I should be a red button </button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

#### And ideally I'd be able to use it like so:

```
<style>
  host-element {
    --menu-button-color: red;
  }
</style>

<host-element><host-element>
```

Comment: css variables behaves like scoped variables. So, your code won't work as it is. You can use default values as one alternate.

Comment: @a1626 If that's the case, it's a bit strange behaviour since this type of value propagation across scopes is semantically correct in nearly any programming context. What do you mean by *default values*? Would you care to expand on that in an answer?

Comment: What i meant to say was they use the rule of inheritance and have to be defined in same or parent scope to work (might not always work with Polymer as it is polyfiled). Default value means something like `color: var(--button-color, var(--default-color))` this way is `button-color` is not defined it falls back to default value which are generally defined in app theme. There are lot of `material` default variables also which polymer team has used to define default values for there standalone elements

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working(chrome), run the code snippet below

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    // Setup Polymer options
    window.Polymer = {
      dom: 'shadow'
    };
  </script>
 
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<style is="custom-style">
  host-elem {
    --menu-button-color: red;
  }
</style>

<body>
  
  <host-elem></host-elem>
  
  <!-- Host Element, includes <child-element> -->
  <dom-module id="host-elem">
    <template>
      <style>
        child-elem { 
          --button-color: var(--menu-button-color);
        }
      </style>
    
      <child-elem><child-elem>
    </template>    
    <script>
    Polymer({ is: 'host-elem'});
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  
  <!-- Child Element, is declared within <host-element> -->
  <dom-module id="child-elem">
    <template>
      <style>
        button { 
          color: var(--button-color);
        }
      </style>
          
      <button>I should be a red button </button>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({ is: 'child-elem'});
    </script>
  </dom-module>    
            
      
</body>
```

Comment: Strange to say the least. I'll double check what's up with my code and get back to this.